# Get a list of days in a year (any year) as d-m

Tags: python, pandas

I need some way to get a list of day-month pairs in a year. The year doesn't matter, except that it can't be a leap year.

Something like this:

`[01-01, 01-02, 01-03, ..., 12-30, 12-31]`

Surely there is some pandorable way to do this using `pd.date_range`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) with default `D` freq (can be omit) with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
#day-month
a = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31').strftime('%d-%m')
print (a[:5])
['01-01' '02-01' '03-01' '04-01' '05-01']
print (a[-5:])
['27-12' '28-12' '29-12' '30-12' '31-12']
```

---

```
#month-day
a = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31').strftime('%m-%d')
print (a[:5])
['01-01' '01-02' '01-03' '01-04' '01-05']
print (a[-5:])
['12-27' '12-28' '12-29' '12-30' '12-31']
```

If want also leap day `Febrary 29` use `2008`, `2012`, `2016` (year divisible 4)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for ;)

Comment: should be `strftime('%m-%d')`?

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.date_range('2001-01-01', periods=365).strftime('%m-%d')
```

or using relatively new (added in Pandas 0.20.0) `origin` feature:

```
pd.to_datetime(np.arange(365), unit='D').strftime('%m-%d')
```

From [what's new](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#to-datetime-has-gained-an-origin-parameter):

> **.to_datetime() has gained an origin parameter**
>
> `to_datetime()` has gained a new parameter, `origin`, to define a
>   reference date from where to compute the resulting timestamps when
>   parsing numerical values with a specific unit specified. ([GH11276](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11276),
>   [GH11745](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11745))
>
> For example, with `1960-01-01` as the starting date:

```
In [14]: pd.to_datetime([1, 2, 3], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('1960-01-01'))
Out[14]: DatetimeIndex(['1960-01-02', '1960-01-03', '1960-01-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

> The default is set at `origin='unix'`, which defaults to `1970-01-01 00:00:00`
>   , which is commonly called `‘unix epoch’` or POSIX time. This
>   was the previous default, so this is a backward compatible change.

```
In [15]: pd.to_datetime([1, 2, 3], unit='D')
Out[15]: DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-02', '1970-01-03', '1970-01-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```